# Google oAuth2 missing required parameter: scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am making a boilerplate for oAuth login using Goole+ API to later use in another project of mine. I'm using an **express** based server and **passport** for my authorization. I followed the docs and defined the strategy as explained and **added a parameter scope** which can be seen in the code below.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");

// Auth using google GET /auth/google
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

// Auth callback GET /auth/google/callback
router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/about");
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

After running the server and going to /auth/google I am getting an ERROR:400 saying invalid request **Missing required parameter: scope**. I found similar questions on Github discussions and here too but some of them were unanswered and the ones which were couldn't help me. I'll really appreciate the help and would love to provide with anything else if it's required. Thanks!

Comment: Have you added a scope parameter in settings?

Comment: Scope parameters must be same in both the client side and IDP settings as well

Comment: @Nishant which settings? Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Yes, if you are using google cloud platform as Identity provider

Comment: I was prompted with it when I was creating my credentials. I can't seem to find that page now. Still looking for it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Nishant okay yeah I found it. GCP and Google's docs are very poorly constructed. Anyway in the scopes the 'profile' scope I want to enable is disabled and I can't seem to click on the checkbox. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: No idea on that.